# How to create the first (Admin) user (CanCan and Devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I made authentication in my Rails 3 app fallowed by [Tony's tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)

I don't want public registrations on my app, just to create new users with Admin account, but I can't create Admin account manually, because in table Users there is encrypted password and salt that must to be generated, and I don't know how :|

Comment: What does this question have to do with CanCan?

Comment: @Mark S...I dont know .?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do it from the rails console.  From the command line goto the directory of your rails application and type `rails console`.  Then enter the following code to create a user:

```
user=User.create!(:email=>'test@test.com',:username=>'test',:password=>'password')
```

This will create a user object (assuming your devise resource is called User).  Now you can use the user object that you just created to set admin privileges.

Comment: I get Template error in browser when I want to access users/new, undefined method 'model', and from console when I try to create new user I get ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error
and a lot of file references (it's not nice to copy in comment :) )

Comment: Where is your ability model? - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Comment: The default devise user model does not have a :username field.

Answer (score 21):

I am current something like this (your details may be different) in my seeds.rb file to create my admin user for Devise.

```
User.new({ :email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'}).save
```

You can execute it using `rake db:seed` in the terminal window.

Answer (score 18):

In addition, if you are using confirmable and want to skip the requirement for a confirmation email when creating new accounts you can do something like this:

```
newuser = User.new({ :email => 'admin@example.com', 
          :password => 'password', 
          :password_confirmation => 'password'})
newuser.skip_confirmation!
newuser.save
```

This is useful if the accounts you are creating are for trusted users or if you are creating test accounts.